# Error while adding Cloudendpoints backend to Android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a Test Android application and have added a cloud-endpoints backend module to it. I have also been able to create a custom class and generate the cloud endpoints for that class. I have also been successfully able to test the endpoint on the localhost server (8080).

However, when I am trying to create an Async task, many problems appear.

1) I am not able to import com.google.api.client libraries that are necessary.

2) I am also not able to import the classes of the backend module in the app MainActivity (i.e. it does not show up as a code error but it does show up as an error when I run the app on my phone)

3) I am not able to commit my code in Github after doing a test run because the path of the backend file is too long to process.

The main activity file is as follows:

```
package com.example.shashank_pc.testcloudendpoints;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}
}
```

The backend module class file (for which I have generated cloudendpoints) is:

```
@Entity
public class TempClass {

@Id
String ID;
int a;

public String getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setID(String ID) {
    this.ID = ID;
}

public int getA() {
    return a;
}

public void setA(int a) {
    this.a = a;
}


}
```

The build gradle for the app-backend is as follows:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.42'
}
}

repositories {
jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.42'
compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.42'
compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.42'
compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.0.3'
}

appengine {
downloadSdk = true
appcfg {
    oauth2 = true
}
endpoints {
    getClientLibsOnBuild = true
    getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
}
}
```

The app module build file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.shashank_pc.testcloudendpoints"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}


dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
}
```

The build gradle for the project is:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: please put compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0') to your Android build file. this should solve the issue with the missing com.google.api.client.libraries